# How to prove the $\alpha$ th derivative of $f(y) = y^{\alpha + \gamma} (1-y)^{\alpha + \gamma}$ is Holder's continuous w.r.t. $\gamma$

Tags: analysis, continuity, lipschitz-functions, holder-inequality

Given $\alpha$ is an integer and $\gamma \in (0, 1]$, $y \in [0,1]$, I'd like to prove $|f^{(\alpha)}(y_1) - f^{(\alpha)}(y_2)| \leq L|y_1 - y_2|^\gamma$, where $f^{(\alpha)}(y)$ is the $\alpha$ th derivative of $f(y) = y^{\alpha + \gamma} (1-y)^{\alpha + \gamma}$.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.